# Find rows that have in the cells duplicates symbols

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that has columns with strings and columns with floats.

some values in the cells have two symbols like this:

> -0.015-0.156  ==> middle '-' is not ok, two dots not ok
>
> 0.014-0.106  ==> middle '-' is not ok, two dots not ok
>
> 0.013.0.156  ==> two dots not ok

> -0.015 ==> ok
>
> 0.013  ==> ok

I want to find all the rows that have a value that is "not ok".

how can I do it?, Maybe with a condition of two dots.

Comment: Is there any other rules? It seems that you can simplify the rule to "checking whether they are numbers".

Comment: numbers it's ok, two dot's is not ok, middle string '-' is not ok.

Comment: Are there any strings that are ok that aren't simple decimal numbers? Tell us about what strings *are* ok, please.

Comment: all string are ok, but the string I wrote don't need to be a string they need to be floats

Comment: `-0.015-0.156`, `0.014-0.106`, `0.013.0.156` can only be represented by strings, so a simple regex will be able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using, [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) by setting error to `coerce`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col":["-0.015-0.156", "0.014-0.106", "0.013.0.156", "-0.015", "0.013"]}
)

df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').isna(), :]
```

---

```
            col
0  -0.015-0.156
1   0.014-0.106
2   0.013.0.156
```

Comment: can these strings be represented as as numbers also?

Comment: Not sure what your asking for here @AnuragDhadse ?

Comment: I mean you use pd.to_numeric which I expect to convert string representation of numbers to int or float but clearly those are not numbers but instead ranges (maybe because of "-" in between)...